# Replace all content within braces?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

In the end I need a regex which basically converts me a phone number into a E164 conform number. As for now i got this:

```
result = s.replaceAll("[(*)|+| ]", "");
```

It replaces everything fine: the spaces, the "+"-sign and also the braces "()". But it does not match the content of its braces, so that e.g. the number `+49 (0)11 111 11 11` will be replaced to `49111111111`.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Why not just strip everything that's not a digit?

Comment: Something simple as replacing all `(\(\d+\)|\D)` with empty string will work for your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it, but what if there's more than just a zero between parentheses?

```
result = s.replaceAll("\\([^()]*\\)|[*+ ]+", "");
```

As a verbose regex:

```
result = s.replaceAll(
    "(?x)     # Allow comments in the regex.                     \n" +
    "\\(      # Either match a (                                 \n" +
    "[^()]*   # then any number of characters except parentheses \n" +
    "\\)      # then a ).                                        \n" +
    "|        # Or                                               \n" +
    "[*+\\ ]+ # Match one or more asterisks, pluses or spaces", "");
```

Comment: He does not want the 0 that is inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted his last sentence.

Comment: this one works perfect! can you please just shortly explain it to me? :)

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as my answer if you have nested parentheses, but it's impossible to handle them really properly just with a single regex (that's not hyperbole, balancing brackets can't be done in a regular language, you need a more powerful formalism such as a context-free grammar).

Answer (score 3):

```
[(*)|+| ]
```

is a character class, matching any single parenthesis, asterisk, bar, plus or space character. Get rid of the square brackets and use something like

```
s.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)|\\D", "");
```

This will remove anything between (and including) parentheses, as well as anything else that is not a digit. Note that this will not handle nested parentheses very well - it will eat everything from an open parenthesis to the first closing one it finds, so would change `(123(45)67)` into `67` (the unbalanced close parenthesis being removed as it's a `\D`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting a little too much magic from [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Firstly, in character classes, don't use `|`. It is just another character that will be matched by the character class. Simply list all the characters you want to include without any delimiters.

Secondly, a character class really just matches single characters. So `(*)` inside a character class can by definition do nothing more than remove `(`, or `*` (literally) or `)`. If you are 100% sure that your input will never have nested parentheses or unmatched parentheses or something, then you can do something like this:

```
"(?:\\([^)]\\)|\\D)+"
```

Comment: You need to double the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this: `"(\\(\\d+\\))|\\+|\\s"`. Removes the paren's and contents, plus sign, and space.